# Excel continues to run after exiting (process still in task manager)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office

<strike>I have begun my first foray into excel.  It seems to pander to the data archiving jobs ive currently undertaken quite well.  Probably should have learned it some time ago.</strike>

One oddity ive noticed that is an annoyance at best, or cause for future concern at worst, is that each time i open a new page, it adds a sequential number to the default title.  For example, im currently on `Book19` for my worksheet.

This happens if i save a worksheet, name it something else, close a blank worksheet and open another.  It doesnt matter - the number keeps increasing each time i close and open excel.

I am trying to understand why it does this and how I can address it.  Otherwise a few days from now i'll be on `Book147` and a few years from now who knows.  Thousands.

Ideally it would begin as whatever the default name is, and thats that.  Book1 I imagine.  If i save it as anything other than Book1, or close it and re-open it I would have assumed it would start on Book1 again.  Unless I have multiple instances of excel open or have saved a Book1 and need to save again it would need an appended name of course.

How can I change the behavior to be more in line with what you'd expect?

I seem to have a problem with excel closing properly/entirely via conventional means.  I first noticed it due to an ever increasing worksheet number.  Was tipped off to what should have been obvious via the first responder below.

Google seems to indicate this isnt unheard of, but i cant find any solution as to why this is happening or how to fix it.  I'm brand new to excel so unsure if theres a setting thats forcing it to stay running or some kind of sync behavior I can disable tied to the M$ account perhaps.

Comment: If you completely Quit Excel and open Task Manager, are there any Excel processes listed there?

Comment: good call, i should have thought to check that.  it does in fact stay open.  I ended the process, and tried anew.  Back to book 1.  Problem is closing it begins the cycle anew.  Aburd to think i'd have to use task manager every time i quit excel.  Best i can tell its happened to others (ala google) but no concrete solution offered.

Comment: Do you have any Macros in your personal macro workbook that may be stopping Excel from closing? Best I can suggest is if this continues, try a Repair operation on Excel or Office.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be related to the Stardock Groupy software.  If tabs are added using Groupy, it wont close properly.  I've posted on their support forum.  Figured id post it here in case someone else runs up against it and is spinning their wheels in the future.

Appears to affect only excel, nothing else from the office suite.